# How to set values of a vertical stem plot as xticks labels?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, xticks

I would like to reverse a grouped data and use group name as xtick label to draw it side by side. below demo mostly good but the label position not as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
  data = [['AAAAAA',8],['AAAAAA',9],['AAAAAA',10],['BBBBBB',5],['BBBBBB',6],['BBBBBB',7],['CCCCCC',1],['CCCCCC',2],['CCCCCC',3],['CCCCCC',4]]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','value'])

  dfg = df.groupby('name')
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
  i = 0
  ymin = df['value'].min()
  c1='#ececec'
  c2='#bcbcbc'
  color=c1  
  for ix, row in reversed(tuple(dfg)):
    print(ix,row)
    n = len(row['name'])
    x = np.linspace(i,i + n,n)
    ax.stem(x,row['value'])

    font_dict = {'family':'serif','color':'darkred', 'size':8}
    ax.text(i + n/2,ymin,ix,ha='right',va='top',rotation=90, fontdict=font_dict)
    if color == c1:
        color = c2
    else:
        color = c1
    
    plt.axvspan(i, i+n, facecolor=color, alpha=0.5)    
    i += len(row)    
    
  ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none') 
  plt.setp( ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
  ax.grid(axis='y',color='gray', linestyle='dashed', alpha=1)    
  ax.spines[["top", "right"]].set_visible(False)
  
  fig.tight_layout() 
    
  plt.show()
  return

main()
```

Output:
[image]

Welcome to comment any other proper way to do this, or how to improve the xticks down, use ymin properly not good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of what you are trying to achieve is correct, here is one way to do it:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["AAAAAA", 8],
        ["AAAAAA", 9],
        ["AAAAAA", 10],
        ["BBBBBB", 5],
        ["BBBBBB", 6],
        ["BBBBBB", 7],
        ["CCCCCC", 1],
        ["CCCCCC", 2],
        ["CCCCCC", 3],
        ["CCCCCC", 4],
    ],
    columns=["name", "value"],
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
i = 0
c1 = "#ececec"
c2 = "#bcbcbc"
color = c1
ticks = {}
```

```py
for ix, row in reversed(tuple(df.groupby("name"))):
    # Create stem plot
    n = len(row["name"])
    x = np.linspace(i, i + n, n)
    ax.stem(x, row["value"])

    # Create axvspan plot 
    if color == c1:
        color = c2
    else:
        color = c1
    ax.axvspan(i, i + n, facecolor=color, alpha=0.5)

    # Save positions and names in a dict
    for key, name in zip(x, row["name"]):
        if key not in ticks.keys():
            ticks[key] = name
        else:
            # Deal with multiple names for same tick
            ticks[key] += f"\n{name}"
    i += len(row)
```

```py
# Add ticks and ticks labels
ax.set_xticks(ticks=list(ticks.keys()))
ax.set_xticklabels(list(ticks.values()), fontsize=10, rotation="vertical")
```

```py
# In Jupyter notebook
fig
```

Output:

[image]

And to avoid repeating the labels, you can, for instance, do:

```py
ax.set_xticklabels(
    [
        "",
        "CCCCCC",
        "",
        "CCCCCC\nBBBBBB",
        "BBBBBB",
        "BBBBBB\nAAAAAA",
        " " * 20 + "AAAAAA",
        "",
    ],
    fontsize=10,
)
```

```
# In Jupyter notebook
fig
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: good, thanks, how can I merge multiple labels into one,e.g. all CCCCC with one in the middle?

Comment: Hi, see my updated answer for one way do to that. Cheers.